# Как узнать количество гласных в символьной строке?

Tags: java

```
String str = "Кількість голосних";
int a = а;
int b = е;
int c = о;
int h = у;
int f = и;
int d = і;
int g = ї;
int j = я;
int u = ю;
int l = є;
int s.length();
char ch = str.charAt(s);
System.out.println(ch)
```

Подскажите, что не так и помогите исправить

Comment: А вы понимаете что вы здесь написали?

Comment: Прекрасный образец непойми чего. Начиная от присвоения `int`-ам неинициилизированных переменных (хоть бы в апострофы их убрали для приличия), продолжная попыткой вывести на печать якобы последнего символа строки `str`, якобы - потому, что и тут не справились, а вышли за границы строки. Последний символ будет на позиции `s-1`. И заканчивая отсутствием какой либо попытки перебрать буквы строки.

Comment: @rjhdby, вероятно, необъявленных, а не неинициализированных. А ещё замечательная строка `int s.length();`

Comment: А почему целочисленному типу присваиваются какие-то странные символы?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну в случае `int` один черт :) А вот строку с `length` проглядел, да. Все еще веселее оказывается

Comment: @rjhdby, вроде char умеет каститься в int? Или это только в шарпе?

Comment: @Qwerti умеет, вот только если он действительно char а не `int g = ї;`

Comment: @Victor, ну это-то понятно)

Comment: @Qwertiy я в том смысле, что для примитивных типов, что необъявленную переменную ему даешь, что null - результат, по большому счему, будет схожим.

Comment: @rjhdby, необъявленная - это гарантированно ошибка компиляции. А вот неинициализированная - зависит от других факторов.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант также и для русского языка. Сравнения независимы от регистра букв.

```
String str = "Кількість голосних + Количество гласных";
Pattern vocals = Pattern.compile("(?iu)[аеёиоуыэюяіїє]");

Matcher m = vocals.matcher(str);
int vocalCounter = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    vocalCounter++;
}
System.out.println("Результат: " + vocalCounter);
```

Для подсчёта используется регулярное выражение *(почему бы и нет)* с гласными буквами. Вначале указываются флаги **CASE_INSENSITIVE** (`i`) для регистро-независимого совпадения и **UNICODE_CASE** (`u`), который заставляет использовать для этого таблицы юникода. Все возможные флаги перечислены в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Метод **find** каждый раз переходит к новому совпадению с регуляркой (т.е. к следующей гласной букве). В принципе, можно было бы даже не писать цикл явно, воспользовавшись группами и подсчитав их количество методом **groupCount**. Но за это пришлось бы заплатить ещё большим падением производительности.

Answer (score 0):

Все у вас не так

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //строка для обработки
        String stringToProc= "Кількість голосних";

        //массив гласных
        char[] vocalArr = new char[]{'а', 'е', 'о', 'у', 'и', 'і', 'ї', 'я', 'ю', 'є'};

        //результат
        int counter = 0;

        //получаем массив
        char[] arrayToProc = stringToProc.toCharArray();

        //вложенный цикл 
        for (char ch : arrayToProc) {
            for (char ch2 : vocalArr) {
                if (ch == ch2){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        //вывод в консоль
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

П.С. Может не запускаться в командной строке из-за укр языка

Comment: После `counter++;` стоит добавить `break;`.

Comment: @Regent согласен, но по сути своей на результат не влияет. *Примечание - код написан на коленке едя в маршрутке